# Long app loading on "cold start" with 2 recycler views

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've started building a new app from scratch, so currently it contains only one activity. This activity contains 2 vertical `RecyclerView`s, first contains 30 `Button`s, then space separating `RecyclerView`s and then second `RecyclerView`, containing 50 `Button`s. Each `RecyclerView` has set `GridLayoutManager`. Any of `RecyclerView` doesn't fetch data from database/network, they have just fixed size and count. When I run this code, it launches in ~ 2 secs and logcat shows skipped frames at rate ~70-80.
When I skip setting layout it launches just fine. 
This is my activity:

```
 private GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager, mSecondManager;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewFirst, mRecyclerViewSecond;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rvAdapter firstAdapter = new rvAdapter();
    rvAdapter2 secondAdapter = new rvAdapter2();

    mRecyclerViewFirst = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
    mRecyclerViewSecond = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);

    mRecyclerViewFirst.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerViewSecond.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    mRecyclerViewFirst.setAdapter(firstAdapter);
    mRecyclerViewSecond.setAdapter(secondAdapter);



}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 8);
        mSecondManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 8);
    } else {
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 5);
        mSecondManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 5);
    }

    mRecyclerViewFirst.setLayoutManager(mSecondManager);
    mRecyclerViewSecond.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

}
```

one of adapters (second is the same, just count different):

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext().getApplicationContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.items_recyclerview, viewGroup, false));
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mButton.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 50;
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private Button mButton;

    private ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        mButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
}
}
```

Layouts: https://gitlab.com/Domin_PL/sample/blob/master/activity_main
I had troubles in adding XML code to stack

This is the whole application for now, so the problem is with LayoutManager. Btw, detecting device's orientation in `onResume` doesn't cause this lag.

Any ideas how can I fix this lag issue? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe your problem comes from the structure of `R.layout.activity_main`, can you share it as well?

Comment: I've added a link to layouts xml code, I had troubles in adding XML code

Comment: Wrapping the two `RecyclerView`s in the root `ScrollView` looks really weird to me. My intuition tells me that it may be the cause of your problem. Having nested scrolling content on the same axis in not a very nice idea and often causes trouble. For investigation purpose, you may try to remove the root node or replace it by a `FrameLayout` and see how it behaves.
If this is the cause of the lag, you should try a single `RecyclerView` handling different view types.

Comment: I've deleted all of them. I've just left 2 RecyclerViews with 2 textviews inside constraintlayout, still ~70 framerate loss. I've updated the code on gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

May be your problem with your xml file . If you use **constraintlayout** for **recyclerview** cell then lagging too much. Because too much load on main ui thread. Avoid constraintlayout in Recyclerview item. Please share your xml file of items of recyclerview.

Comment: XML item is just a a button with a root of button. No other layouts inside.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it down to an average 30~35 skipped frames upon cold launch of the app. I used a single `RecyclerView` with different view types and `ViewHolder`s for the titles and the buttons. Here is the code with which I obtained the that result:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RvAdapter(
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark),
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)
        ));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        final int columnCount = orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 8 : 5;
        final GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), columnCount);

        layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int i) {
                return (i == 0 || i == 31) ? columnCount : 1;
            }
        });

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**RvAdapter.java**

```
public class RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int BUTTON_FIRST_GROUP_COUNT = 30;
    private static final int BUTTON_SECOND_GROUP_COUNT = 50;

    private static final int TYPE_TITLE = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_BUTTON = 1;

    @ColorInt
    private final int colorPrimary;
    @ColorInt
    private final int colorWhite;

    private String[] content = new String[BUTTON_FIRST_GROUP_COUNT + BUTTON_SECOND_GROUP_COUNT + 2 /* titles */];

    RvAdapter(@ColorInt final int colorPrimary, @ColorInt final int colorWhite) {
        this.colorPrimary = colorPrimary;
        this.colorWhite = colorWhite;

        initContent();
    }

    private void initContent() {
        for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            final String prefix = isTitle(i) ? "Title " : "";
            content[i] = prefix + (i + 1);
        }
    }

    private boolean isTitle(final int position) {
        return (position == 0 || position == BUTTON_FIRST_GROUP_COUNT + 1);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

        if (viewType == TYPE_TITLE) {
            return new TitleViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_title, viewGroup, false));
        }
        return new ButtonViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_button, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String currentContent = content[position];

        if (holder instanceof TitleViewHolder) {
            final TitleViewHolder titleViewHolder = (TitleViewHolder) holder;
            titleViewHolder.mTextView.setText(currentContent);
        } else {
            final ButtonViewHolder buttonViewHolder = (ButtonViewHolder) holder;

            buttonViewHolder.setBackgroundColor(position <= BUTTON_FIRST_GROUP_COUNT ? colorPrimary : colorWhite);
            buttonViewHolder.mButton.setText(currentContent);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return isTitle(position) ? TYPE_TITLE : TYPE_BUTTON;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return content.length;
    }
}
```

Hope that it is going to help you.